# Can I simply isolate Ethernet ports from one another without the complexity of VLAN?

Tags: ethernet, dhcp

I'm to set up Internet access for a building.  Each office-suite has a hardwired Ethernet cable.  I'm going to have each tenant bring their own WiFi/LAN router to plug into their Ethernet cable to service their suite.  Then I'd like to have an Ethernet switch that keeps each Ethernet port isolated, so that the tenants cannot access (or even detect) each others' devices.

I'd likely have my router assign IP address ranges to each tenant's router and let them run in router mode.  Or maybe I'd have a large DHCP server that assigns all the IP addresses while routers run in WAC mode.  Whichever works best for isolated Ethernet ports.

Comment: If your business internet has multiple IP addresses (common), assign each business with its own external IP address and then their circuits are isolated from each other. This is simple conceptually and works well.

Comment: @John, yuo mean static / leased external IP addresses?  That's rather expensive isn't it?

Comment: You need to ask the ISP about pricing for multiple IP addresses.  My clients usually get 6 IP addresses with their service. If you need more, you need to ask about pricing .

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is
[Private VLAN / Port Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_VLAN),
described as:

> **Private VLAN**, also known as **port isolation**, is a technique in computer networking where a VLAN contains switch ports that are restricted such that they can only communicate with a given "uplink". The restricted ports are called "private ports". Each private VLAN typically contains many private ports, and a single uplink. The uplink will typically be a port (or link aggregation group) connected to a router, firewall, server, provider network, or similar central resource.

You should ensure that whatever switch you buy supports this option.

See the descriptions for Port Isolation from
[NETGEAR](https://kb.netgear.com/24702/What-are-protected-ports-on-a-smart-switch?cid=wmt_netgear_organic)
and
[CISCO](https://meraki.cisco.com/blog/2015/03/new-switch-feature-provides-port-isolation/).

Comment: Thx for this answer.  Looks like it could work.  But let me ask.  Upstream from this switch is the Cable Modem / main router.  Do I need to do anything to stop that main router from forwarding traffic from an IP on one Ethernet port to an IP on another Ethernet port?  Do I need to stop the router itself from acting as a bridge?

Comment: That depends on the switch and its configuration. See [this article](https://kb.netgear.com/21618/What-are-private-VLANs-and-how-do-they-work-with-my-managed-switch) about "Isolated ports", so you could ask about it when shopping for the switch.